# Objective C -- narrow instance variable types in subclasses?

Tags: iphone, ios, subclassing

Is it possible to narrow the allowed type of an ivar in a subclass.  Something like this:

```
@interface person: NSObject {
  NSArray *friendArray;
}

@interface mutablePerson: person {
  NSMutableArray *friendArray;
}
```

I just tried that exact code, and Xcode gave me a compile error.  I'm wondering if there is a way around it.

The project I am working on is going to have a lot of this sort of situation.  I understand that I can use casts to make the code work.  But I will be making an awful lot of casts if I do that, and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: 1) Narrowing isn't allowed, but you have widened it, which is.  2) You are declaring the same member name again - you can't do that.  give it a new name and change the accessors.

Comment: have you tried/implemented NSMutableCopying protocol? probably is what you want.

Comment: @Alex Brown. It has narrowed. `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`.

Comment: It's widened.  NSMutableArray is at least as capable as NSArray.  Someone grabbing an NSMutableArray thinking it was an NSArray will experience no odd effects, therefore the API to your class and it's new subclass has not changed.

Comment: http://help-abap.blogspot.com/2008/09/abap-objects-narrowing-cast-upcasting.html

Comment: @Alex Brown. I think you may be right, my brain has given up for the day. I'm more used to the term 'downcast'. I find that easier to understand: a 'downcast' goes 'down' the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended overriding the setter to assert that the object being set is of the appropriate type, and creating a new read-only getter, like this:

```
@interface MutablePerson {
}

@property (readonly) NSMutableArray *mutableFriendArray;

@implementation MutablePerson

-(NSMutableArray *) mutableFriendArray {
  NSMutableArray *ret = (NSMutableArray *)[super friendArray];
  NSAssert ([ret isKindOfClass: [NSMutableArray class]], @"array should be mutable");
  return ret;
}

-(void) setFriendArray: (NSMutableArray *) array {
  NSAssert ([array isKindOfClass: [NSMutableArray class]], @"array should be mutable");
  [super setFriendArray: array];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't redeclare ivars at all.  However, you can make a new method based property without making a new ivar.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray* mutableFriends;

@implementation MutablePerson

- (NSMutableArray*)mutableFriends {
  return (NSMutableArray*)friendArray;
}

- (void)setMutableFriends:(NSMutableArray*)friends {
  self.friendsArray = [friends mutableCopy];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

@class doesn't make sense at all... it should be @interface. So the first error is purely syntactical.

And no, you cannot change the type of an ivar. And that's for a good reason: Narrowing it down (as you do) can't work, because the parent class might rely on a different implementation. Widening it can't work as well (mainly for the analogous reason.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the code here; it was correct when I tried it in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler says 'no' then that's your answer. I would use accessors:

```
//Person
-(NSArray *)friends;


//MutablePerson
-(void)addFriend:(person *)friend;
```

In the `MutablePerson` you could declare another array to store `friends` or you could access the ivar directly in `addFriend:`:

```
-(void)addFriend:(person *)friend
{
    _friendsArray = [_friendsArray arrayByAddingObject: friend];
}
```

Accessing ivars directly isn't smart. I would reconsider your class design. What's the rationale for having a mutable and immutable versions of person?