# "Subclassing" a variable in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C — narrow instance variable types in subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248066/objective-c-narrow-instance-variable-types-in-subclasses)

I have a class called `ParentClass` which has a `UIView` property. I also have a class called `ChildClass` which is a subclass of `ParentClass`. `ChildClass` obviously inherits the `UIView` property, but in `ChildClass` I know for certain I'll only be using a `UIScrollView` for this property.

My question is, is it possible / feasible to somehow "subclass" the `UIView` property, rename it, and make it so it can only be a `UIScrollView`? Would I have to override the property in the .m file when I synthesize?

Similar to how a `UITableViewController`'s main view property is a `UITableView` rather than a `UIView` as in `UIViewController`.

UPDATE: Maybe I just didn't mean property, but also the variable itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a property with the same name to your child class but with UIScrollView instead of `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're subclassing `ParentClass`, that has a property of a `UIView` and you need `ChildClass` to inherit a `UIScrollView`.. You should just make a `UIScrollView` property in `ParentClass` so `ChildClass` can inherit and use it.

If `ChildClass` isn't going to use the `UIView` property, if you never initialize it will remain `nil` therefor not using up any of your memory. Also giving you the benefit, if and or when you choose to use the `UIView` property you can.

Alternatively, simply declare a new `UIScrollView` property in `ChildClass` if you don't want to in `ParentClass`

Hope this made sense, and helps !

Answer (score 0):

Properties are converted into methods, and these methods can be overridden just like any other. You can do something like this:

```
@interface ParentClass {
    NSView* myView;
}
@property(retain) NSView* myView;
@end

@implementation ParentClass
@synthesize myView;
@end

@interface ChildClass
@end

@implementation ChildClass
-(void) setMyView:(NSView*)v;
{
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        [super setMyView:v];
    } else {
        //do whatever error handling you want to here
    }
}
@end
```

The `-setMyView:` method is one of the methods that the property was converted into, so defining it in `ChildClass` will override the one on the parent class.

Side note: when you refer to "subclassing" the property, the correct term is "overriding."

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated and code duplication, since you can achieve this barely by overriding the property as they said before.

Comment: Overriding the property isn't going to check the type in the setter.